How do you actually link Real World Asset to newly issued tokens?
I've been exploring possibilities to tokenize real world assets, such as a real estate, and I came across the concept called Real World Asset Tokenization link.
Aside from all the gibberish about how good is it and why we need this, I want to know how you can actually link the real world asset to newly issued token.
What do you think are the possible ways of doing this?
For example, uploading all the real estate related documents to IPFS and put that IPFS address into the contract?
Or is it inherently impossible?
Would love any feedbacks from you guys.

I came across this website RealT as an advertisement on Ethereum Unit Converter website. So, the way they're selling various tokenized real estates might be informative for your use-case.

Super interesting. So the company is acting as a central authority and is likely dispensing collected rental fees from the tenants to the token holders.
